Middleware : Route [login] not defined
In laravel 11, i want to make a middleware when the user was not authenticated they are redirected to login page, but there are no more default middleware Authenthicate in laravel 11 so i make that middleware, but the result is Route [login] not defined.
I make the Authenticate middleware like this
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Authenthicate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('admin.auth.index');
        }
    }
}

And my web.php route
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function (){
    Route::view('/login', 'login')->name('admin.auth.index');
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.auth.login');
});


Route::middleware([Authenticate::class])->group(function () {
    Route::view('/', 'dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
});


And this is my login view

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>BWA Bank | Log in</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('AdminLTE/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css') }}">
  <!-- icheck bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('AdminLTE/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css') }}">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('AdminLTE/dist/css/adminlte.min.css') }}">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="#"><b>Admin</b> BWA BANK</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

      {{-- alert here --}}
      @if (session('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{session('error')}}
        </div>
      @endif

      <form action="{{route('admin.auth.login')}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="{{old('email')}}">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="{{old('password')}}">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{{ asset('AdminLTE/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="{{ asset('AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{{ asset('AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>



Why am i getting this error? And how to fix this?

Laravel 11 also has middleware for Guest user. Please see. Also please add your view file code. It seems you had specified wrong route to your login view.

Check you all routes using this command php artisan route:list ,also clear the route cache using this command php artisan route:clear. Check that whether route list shows this route admin.auth.login.

There are my route list :
GET|HEAD  / ................................................... admin.dashboard
GET|HEAD  admin/login ........................................ admin.auth.index
POST      admin/login ........... admin.auth.login › Admin\AuthController@login

I think the confusion is that you're using the wrong middleware in your route definitions. Keep an eye on the namespace here:
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate; //here
Route::middleware([Authenticate::class])->group(function () {
    Route::view('/', 'dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
});

As you can see, you're importing and using Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate instead of your custom middleware. There are two solutions to this:

Use custom name for your middleware using middleware aliases, inside your boostrap/app.php file:

use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
   $middleware->alias([
      'auth.custom' => Authenticate::class
   ]);
})

And use it in route like this:
Route::middleware(['auth.custom'])->group(function () {
    Route::view('/', 'dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
});


Change the namespace in the web.php file to:

use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate

